# Add dependecy on another module while building a kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel-module, autoconf, automake, kbuild

I am trying trying to use an external module that I have written from another kernel module. The second module is the cr_module from the Berkeley lab checkpoint/restart).

So, I create a module A that exports some functions and then created another module B which uses A's functions. I installed the module A so that its headers go with the rest of headers in the linux sources. Module B can not include the headers and link to Module A's functions when I copy the Module.symvers file from Module A sources to Module B sources. This way all goes fine.

However, since blcr uses automake and autconf I can not figure out how to tell kbuild to use Module A's functions. I copied Module A's Module.symvers to all subdirectories in blcr but still it can not link to those functions. Somehow modpost can not see this file (Module.symvers).

Any help figuring this out?

Thanks.